# creating objects with multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, object

is there an easier way to set multiple lines of a file into an object without typing them all out
Ive got a json array which has parsed a file into an array
i have set each element to a variable

```
id = array[0];   
name = array[1];
position = array[2];
```

and put it in a for loop where it inputs it into an object class i have created.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < array.length(); ii++)
        {
            Employee [] employee {new Employees (id, name, position)};
        }
```

i tried to print out the object class however it just stored each into its own separe object instead of one big one
the only way ive figure is to do

```
Employee[] employee = {
            new Employee(1210, "Bob", ceo),
            new Employee(2210, "Tom", manager),
            new Employee(3210, "Terry", teacher),
            new Employee(40211 "Joe", student)
        };
```

however my file code is 1000+ lines and i can't afford to be entering it all in, is there a quicker way to do this or a trick with the for loops im missing

ALSO
im trying to call my toString method from my object class and ive done System.out.println(employee.toString()) however it prints out: Before sorting => [Employee;@a09ee92 After sorting => [Employee;@a09ee92 the address memory instead of the actual values, Arrays.toString does work although i cannot use ADT's

thank you

Comment: If you have the data as well formatted JSON you could use a JSON parser like GSON to create your java object from the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do this but you need to get all the information into separate arrays (or use the a JSON parser as recommended in the comments). presumes the source arrays are all the same length.

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[id.length];
for (int ii = 0; ii < array.length(); ii++) {
            // if you don't have all the information in three arrays
            // and you need to create each array of three items as you read
            // the file you could do that here.
            employees [ii]  = new Employee(id[ii], name[ii], position[ii])};
}
```

Then to print them you can do this.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employees));
```

Or iterate thru the list with a for loop.  Note that for the output to be meaningful you need to override the `toString()` method in you `Employee` class.